# How can I match everything with a PHP regular expression?

Tags: php, regex

How can I match everything with a PHP regular expression?  I tried: /[.\r\n]*/, but it isn't working.  Any ideas?  Thanks.

This is for a method I made for a PHP class to parse e-mails:

```
public function getHeader($headerName) { 
    preg_match('/[\r\n]' . $headerName . '[:][ ](.+)[\r\n][^ \t]/Uis', "\n" . ltrim($this->originalMessage), $matches); return preg_replace('/[\r\n]*/', '', $matches[1]); 
    }
```

Comment: You probably need to clarify a bit, since if you really want to match *everything* there´s no need for matching at all. Just do whatever you need to do with the source itself.

Comment: I hope you're not just matching everything to circumvent taint checking.

Answer (score 9):

`/.*/s` (see [perl's docs](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html)). The `s` option means (quoting from that URL):

> Treat string as single line. (Make . match a newline)

Answer (score 6):

I assume, based on your inclusion of `\n` and `\r` above, that you want to match *across* multiple lines.  In this case, use:

`/.*/s`

(note the explicit `/s` modifier, that is, change `.` to match any character whatsoever, even a newline, which it normally would not match.)

See http://www.perl.com/doc/manual/html/pod/perlre.html

Answer (score 2):

Why do you want to match everything? There's no point in using it as a condition because it's always true. If you want to capture the text you don't need a regex to do it because you just use the entire string. If you're trying to get around taint-checking, then shame on you (and ask a separate question about doing that right).

Note that we have a bit of the [XY Problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=542341) here. You have some task X in mind, and think Y is part of the solution. You ask about Y but never tell us X. It's hard to answer your real question when we don't know what you are trying to do. :)

Comment: It sounds like your real question is "How do I extract email headers with PHP?". Surely there's a PHP class that already does that.

Answer (score 0):

What about /.*/s?

In a character class ( the [] ), . just means period.

Comment: That isn't matching new lines.

Comment: Yes, it is matching new lines: perl -e 'print "matches\n" if "\n" =~ m/\A.*\z/s'

Answer (score 0):

Does `/[\.\r\n]+/` do what you want?

This kludge has also worked for me before:

```
my $abstract_text = /Abstract:([\s\S]+?)\nReferences/m;
```

It's useful if you want to capture patterns with arbitrary text included or intervening between multiple captures.